# Do CUDA cores have vector instructions?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

According to most NVidia documentation CUDA cores are scalar processors and should only execute scalar operations, that will get vectorized to 32-component SIMT warps.

But OpenCL has vector types like for example `uchar8`.It has the same size as `ulong` (64 bit), which can be processed by a single scalar core. If I do operations on a `uchar8` vector (for example component-wise addition), will this also map to an instruction on a single core?

If there are 1024 work items in a block (work group), and each work items processes a `uchar8`, will this effectively process 8120 `uchar` in parallel?

**Edit:**
My question was if on CUDA architectures specifically (independently of OpenCL), there are some vector instructions available in "scalar" cores. Because if the core is already capable of handling a 32-bit type, it would be reasonable if it can also handle addition of a 32-bit `uchar4` for example, especially since vector operations are often used in computer graphics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are GPU/CUDA cores SIMD ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283970/are-gpu-cuda-cores-simd-ones)

Comment: While the title of the question is very similar, it is not (that) duplicate. The other question asks about SIMD which in fact is handled by the warp. Here the author asks about sub-register operations, e.g. packing 8 8-bit values into a single 64-bit regular register and performing a meaningful operation on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CUDA has "built-in" (i.e. predefined) vector types up to a size of 4 for 4-byte quantities (e.g. `int4`) and up to a size of 2 for 8-byte quantities (e.g. `double2`).  A CUDA thread has a maximum read/write transaction size of 16 bytes, so these particular size choices tend to line up with [that maximum](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).

These are exposed as typical structures, so you can reference for example `.x` to access just the first element of a vector type.

Unlike OpenCL, CUDA does not provide built-in operations ("overloads") for basic arithmetic e.g. `+`, `-`, etc. for element-wise operations on these vector types.  There's no particular reason you couldn't provide such overloads yourself.  Likewise, if you wanted a `uchar8` you could easily provide a structure definition for such, as well as any desired operator overloads.  These could probably be implemented just as you would expect for ordinary C++ code.

Probably an underlying question is, then, what is the difference in implementation between CUDA and OpenCL in this regard?  If I operate on a `uchar8`, e.g.

```
uchar8 v1 = {...};
uchar8 v2 = {...};
uchar8 r = v1 + v2;
```

what will the difference be in terms of machine performance (or low-level code generation) between OpenCL and CUDA?

Probably not much, for a CUDA-capable GPU.  A CUDA core (i.e. the underlying ALU) does not have direct native support for such an operation on a `uchar8`, and furthermore, if you write your own C++ compliant overload, you're probably going to use C++ semantics for this which will inherently be serial:

```
r.x = v1.x + v2.x;
r.y = v1.y + v2.y;
...
```

So this will decompose into a sequence of operations performed on the CUDA core (or in the appropriate integer unit within the CUDA SM).  Since the NVIDIA GPU hardware doesn't provide any direct support for an 8-way uchar add within a single core/clock/instruction, there's really no way OpenCL (as implemented on a NVIDIA GPU) could be much different.  At a low level, the underlying machine code is going to be a sequence of operations, not a single instruction.

As an aside, CUDA (or PTX, or CUDA intrinsics) does provide for a limited amount of vector operations within a single core/thread/instruction.  Some examples of this are:

1. a limited set of "native" ["video" SIMD instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#video-instructions).  These instructions are per-thread, so if used, they allow for "native" support of up to 4x32 = 128 (8-bit) operands per warp, although the operands must be properly packed into 32-bit registers.  You can access these from C++ directly via a set of built-in [intrinsics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD). (A CUDA *warp* is a set of 32 threads, and is the fundamental unit of lockstep parallel execution and scheduling on a CUDA capable GPU.)
2. a vector (SIMD) multiply-accumulate operation, which is not directly translatable to a single particular elementwise operation overload, the so-called int8 dp2a and dp4a instructions.  int8 here is somewhat misleading.  It does not refer to an int8 vector type but rather a packed arrangement of 4 8-bit integer quantities in a single 32-bit word/register.  Again, these are accessible via [intrinsics](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/).
3. 16-bit floating point is natively supported via `half2` vector type in cc 5.3 and higher GPUs, for certain operations.
4. The new Volta tensorCore is something vaguely like a SIMD-per-thread operation, but it operates (warp-wide) on a set of 16x16 input matrices producing a 16x16 matrix result.

Even with a smart OpenCL compiler that could map certain vector operations into the various operations "natively" supported by the hardware, it would not be complete coverage.  There is no operational support for an 8-wide vector (e.g. `uchar8`) on a single core/thread, in a single instruction, to pick one example.  So some serialization would be necessary.  In practice, I don't think the OpenCL compiler from NVIDIA is that smart, so my expectation is that you would find such per-thread vector operations fully serialized, if you studied the machine code.

In CUDA, you could provide your own overload for *certain* operations and vector types, that could be represented approximately in a single instruction.  For example a `uchar4` add could be performed "natively" with the [__vadd4() intrinsic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD_1g985e19defa6381f163004ac5dd6e68e8) (perhaps included in your implementation of an operator overload.)  Likewise, if you are writing your own operator overload, I don't think it would be difficult to perform a `uchar8` elementwise vector add using two `__vadd4()` instructions.

Answer (score 1):

See documentation [1.12. SIMD Intrinsics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD) of the CUDA Toolkit documentation.

It has such things as `__vadd4()` for 4x8bit and `__vadd2()` for 2x16bit SIMD.

Answer (score -1):

> If I do operations on a uchar8 vector (for example component-wise addition), will this also map to an instruction on a single core?

AFAIK it'll always be on a single core (instructions from a single kernel / workitem don't cross cores, except special instructions like barriers), but it may be more than one instruction. This depends on whether your hardware support operations on uchar8 natively. If it does not, then uchar8 will be broken up to as many pieces as required, and each piece will be processed with a separate instruction.

OpenCL is very "generic" in the sense that it supports many different vector type/size combos, but real-world hardware usually only implements some vector type/size combinations. You can query OpenCL devices for "preferred vector size" which should tell you what's the most efficient for that hardware.